# Centering rotated graphicPath using the Matrix object in C#

Tags: c#, matrix, rotation

I am writing a library that will create a graphihc path (In the shape of a polygon or rectangle) and rotate it but I want the rotated shape to be centered within its bounding rectangle. I have tried almost everything to get the shape to rotate on its center but it cutting off at the edges.

Below is some smaple code I have written to try to accomplish this

```
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddPolygon(new Point[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(100, 0), new Point(100, 100), new Point(0, 100) });
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        Matrix m2 = new Matrix();
        m2.Rotate(30);
        m.Translate(-((path.GetBounds(m2).Width) / 2), -((path.GetBounds(m2).Height) / 2));
        m.Rotate(30, MatrixOrder.Append);
        m.Translate(((path.GetBounds(m2).Width)/2), ((path.GetBounds(m2).Height)/2), MatrixOrder.Append);
        path.Transform(m);
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap((int)path.GetBounds().Width, (int)path.GetBounds().Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);

        g.FillPath(Brushes.Blue, path);

        b.Save(@"c:\aSSETS\sample3.png");
```

Please help. Thanks